# What are recommended methods to install WAS(Websphere 9) on more than one server?

Tags: websphere

I am aware of the process to install WAS 8.5.5.x and 9.0.x versions using IM response file(s) but would like to know best practices and recommendations to perform WAS installation and upgrade on more than one server, to avoid manual errors and reduce time.

I am open to use to Ansible, Puppet or any other orchestration tools as well, but would like to know possible options if we are not allowed to use these tools.

Ultimate goal is to automate most of the setup/upgrade steps, if not all of them since when dealing with bunch of servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to WebSphere Application Server traditional, take a look at the approaches described here, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_enterprise_install.html, especially if you are working with larger scale deployments.

Consider creating master images and distributing them in a swinging profile-type setup.  They make it easier and faster to install and apply updates since you only need to create images once and distribute many times.  You have consistency across systems too.

You can then automate with your preferred automation technology.

Comment: Good to know about this feature, could you please elaborate on "creating master images and distributing them in a swinging profile-type setup" since the documentation is not clear for these steps?

Comment: I read docs at `https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_sp_overview.html` and got little better understanding of the concepts. Based on this it appears that it's a matter of copying the master image from one server to the other for a fresh install or upgrade. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You will create images of the binaries that you want to distribute from a common location. Your profiles will be (created) on the target systems. You then link the binaries to the profile and easily update by replacing the binaries with a new 'image'. The procedures are described in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_sm_images.html and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_sp_overview.html, which you found.

Comment: Great, this is very helpful information, got a hang of it after reading it again.

Answer (score 1):

We use ansible, simple and effectively.
True, you must of course develop a playbook that will be able to do all this.

Comment: Are there any IBM Ansible playbooks for this purpose or you were on your own?

Comment: We did this on our own, and in combination with the jenkins pipeline + ansible. I don’t think that IBM has them, and even if they were, it would probably be much harder to figure them out than to write it yourself.

Comment: Good to know. How does Jenkins pipeline help with installs, or were you referring to the application application set up & deployment?